# I can't find the mistake in this argument (Cofinality and König's theorem)

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I have some trouble explaining this apparent contradiction:

we know that given $k>\aleph_0$ an infinite cardinal, $\mu=cof(k)$ is the minimum cardinal such that $k=\sum_{i\in \mu} k_i$ where $|k_i|<k$.

But, using König's theorem $\sum_{i\in \mu} k_i< \prod_{i\in \mu} k=k\mu=k$ and apparently we get $k<k$.

Where is my mistake?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is that $$\prod_\mu\kappa=\kappa^\mu$$
And the result of the theorem is that it is indeed larger than $\kappa$

Comment: Thank you!
Then $|\mathbb{R}|^{\aleph_0}>|\mathbb{R}|$, is that right?

Comment: No, that is the opposite of right. We can easily prove equality by remembering that $|\Bbb R|=2^{\aleph_0}$. This is why we know that the cofinality of the cardinal of the continuum is not $\aleph_0$.

Comment: Why isn't $cof(\mathbb{R})=\aleph_0$? $\mathbb{N}$ is cofinal in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: You are mixing cofinality of a linear order, and cofinality of cardinals (which is the same as the cofinality of the least well ordering of $\Bbb R$).

Comment: Can you please explain this in details? thank you!

Comment: Ok. I think now I understand what you're saying. I can't consider $\mathbb{R}$ as a cardinal with its "usual" order, since it wouldn't be well ordered

Comment: Yes, that is the issue.